# Linking a php page within a jsp page using <a> tag

Tags: java, php, jsp, tomcat, xampp

Is it possible to link to a php page from a jsp page? I have a jsp page which is running on a tomcat server in eclipse, in that jsp page if I give a  tag and link it to a php page whch is running on xampp will it work ? i Tried it but i dont see any results

index.jsp code :

```
<a href="c:/xamp/htdoc/file/test.php">Test this php file</a>
```

test.php code

```
 <?php
  <h1>It works !!</h1>
  ?>
```

Comment: Please show the exact HTML you get out fo the jps.

Answer (score 0):

the href has to be a valid URL for it to work on a server, so probably what you are after is something like

```
<a href="http://myPhpServer/test.php">Test this php file</a>
```

Of course replace it will valid server / context values

Answer (score 0):

you must run php server before try link on jsp page. your url should look like this

```
<a href="http://localhost/test.php">Test this php file</a>
```